# Syntax Error printing variables on Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am getting a syntax error on my Python code. The IDLE isn't giving any tips to where the error might be.

I am running Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

```
inches = input "How many inches?"
cm = inches*2.54
print "That is" {} "centimeters.".format(cm)
```

I expected the output to ask me how many inches I wanted to convert. It then would have stated the value of centimeters that it is equal to.

Instead, it comes up with a window that says "Syntax Error." and no other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must cover the string inside parenthesis.

```py
inches = input("How many inches?")
```

but that's not enough, you need a number to perform multiplication operator. So cover your `input()` with `float()` for float number or `int()` for integer.

```py
inches = float(input("How many inches?"))
# or
inches = int(input("How many inches?"))
```

unlike python 2, in python 3, `print()` is a built-in function, its parameter must be put inside parenthesis. Also, brackets `{}` must be put in quotes.

```py
print("That is {} centimeters.".format(cm))
```

So your code may look like:

```py
inches = int(input("How many inches?")) # or inches = float(input("How many inches?")) 
cm = inches*2.54
print("That is {} centimeters.".format(cm))
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write this is

```py
inches = input("How many inches?")
cm = inches*2.54
print("That is %f centimeters" % (cm))
```

The % means that you will insert a value here the character which follow id the type of the variable that you will insert here i use %f for float yout could also use %s for string for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
inches = input("How many inches?")
cm = inches*2.54
print("That is" {} "centimeters.".format(cm))
```

Comment: Check the `quotes` in print statement and wrap input into `int` or `float` as it is used for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your Python version on your Raspberry PI. F strings were introduced in 3.6 and if your PI is like mine the default Python version installed will be 3.5

Also print calls need parentheses e.g. print()